# Electromagnetism in flat space

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

I want to get a deeper understanding of how Electric and Magnetic fields transform under Lorentz transformation. That is how to start from gauge transformation of Electric and Magnetic fields

$$E= -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} - \nabla\phi $$ 
and
$$B= \nabla \times A$$
in order to fill in the $F^{\mu\nu} $ matrix.

I am then interested in proving that $$E_x' = E_x $$

I have searched lots of books and didn't find a very thorough explanation.

Any reference to book or paper or online lecture notes will be highly appreciated.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: The gauge transformation is unrelated to the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: I meant the forms of E and B I wrote in the question in order to proceed.

Comment: Why would you expect the x component of the electric field not to transform under a Lorentz transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, any spatial rotation isn't going to do anything interesting to the Electric Field as a vector, but its components are going to change!

Restricting to Lorentz Boosts along $x$

$$\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}=\begin{bmatrix} \gamma &-\beta\gamma&0&0\\-\beta\gamma&\gamma&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So

$$F'^{\sigma\tau}=\Lambda^{\sigma}_\mu\Lambda^\tau_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$$

and specifically,

$$ F'^{01}=\Lambda^{0}_\mu\Lambda^1_\nu F^{\mu\nu} $$

Expanding in indicies in non-zero components

$$ F'^{01}=\Lambda^{0}_0\Lambda^1_\nu F^{0\nu}+\Lambda^{0}_1\Lambda^1_\nu F^{1\nu}=\Lambda^{0}_0\Lambda^1_0 F^{00}+\Lambda^{0}_1\Lambda^1_0 F^{10}+\Lambda^{0}_0\Lambda^1_1 F^{01}+\Lambda^{0}_1\Lambda^1_1 F^{11} $$

$$ F'^{01}=(-\beta\gamma)(-\beta\gamma)F^{10}+ \gamma\gamma F^{01}$$

Using Antisymmetry of $F^{\mu\nu}$

$$ F'^{01}=\gamma^2(1-\beta^2)F^{01}=\frac{1-\beta^2}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}^2}F^{01} $$

$$ F'^{01}=F^{01}  $$

The component representing $E_x$ is therefore unchanged.